# Passing a variable to a form in Edge Animate

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

I need to pass a variable to a form from Edge Animate.
I have the following instruction:

```
sym.$("form").append('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="login_PRA.php?v_id="vidn frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```

vidn is a variable but used as I did it has passed as a value 
so when I need to access the value contained by the variable vidn 
I just get "vidn". Please can you help me to write correctly instruction?

Comment: Break down the question into smaller problems. At the moment there are too many issues for us to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the correct solution and I had already posted it yesterday and I don't know why I can't see it here. the correct solution is:

```
sym.$("form").append('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="login_PRA.php?v_id=' + vidn + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```